# Getting a"TypeError: object.__init()__ takes no arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to implement the graphical part of a game that I wrote using kivy.  Since I am new to kivy I went through ts documentation which I found some programming samples that I studied and used. In one of the samples, I get:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

Here is the code:

```
from kivy.app import App;
from kivy.uix.label import Label;
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout;
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput;

class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        #super(LoginScreen, self).__new__(**kwargs) # == super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwagrs) 
        #GridLayout.__init__()
        super().__init__(**kwargs);
        self.cols = 2 # The colors

        # Creating the Object for username and then adding it into Canvans 
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Username: "))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

        # Creating the Object for password and then adding it into Canvans
        self.add_widget(None,Label(Text="password:"))
        self.password = TextInput(password=True,multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.password)

class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen();

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SimpleKivy().run();
```

Comment: Show us the call that produces the error. What was the input? You need to show the problem you're asking about.

Comment: @ Chris Johnson I am at work right but will finish at 2am. If you are patient I will update the post when I get home thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```
self.add_widget(None,Label(Text="password:"))
```

You don't need to use `None`, and change `Text=` to `text=` because kivy's keyword args are all lowercase. So change it to:

```
self.add_widget(Label(text="password:"))
```

Also, have a look at [Kv language](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html) it is useful for building apps with kivy.

Comment: I have fixed them but still getting the error.Will add the shot-screen soon.

Comment: @EmmanuelKofyAgyapong "change `Text=` to `text=`" - this fixes error.